# Renaming Search Index drive in WFE servers

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, search, index, network-drive

Right now, our search index is on D:\ which is a Temporary Storage and our E:\ is Data drive.

Our Windows team is planning to rename E:\ to D:\ and vice versa.Which would mean,Search index files will be on Temporary drive(E:) after renaming.

Will copy pasting the Search index files to current E:\ (to be renamed as D:/ later) create any problem after renaming? Or what is the best way to move the search index files to another drive?

Answer (score 0):

Use the powershell script to move the index location, which is safe and easy I think.

You have to make sure the all the crawls are stoped and search topology is error free.

You have to execute the below code

```
function Move-SPEnterpriseSearchIndex($SearchServiceName,$Server,$IndexLocation){ 
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ea 0; 
    #Gets the Search Service Application 
    $SSA = Get-SPServiceApplication -Name $SearchServiceName; 
    if (!$?){throw "Cant find a Search Service Application: `"$SearchServiceName`"";} 
    #Gets the Search Service Instance on the Specified Server 
    $Instance = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance -Identity $Server; 
    if (!$?){throw "Cant find a Search Service Instance on Server: `"$Server`"";} 
    #Gets the current Search Topology 
    $Current = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -SearchApplication $SSA -Active; 
    if (!$?){throw "There is no Active Topology, you can try removing the `"-Active`" from the line above in the script";} 
    #Creates a Copy of the current Search Topology 
    $Clone = New-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -Clone -SearchApplication $SSA -SearchTopology $Current; 
    #Adds a new Index Component with the new Index Location 
    New-SPEnterpriseSearchIndexComponent -SearchTopology $Clone -IndexPartition 0 -SearchServiceInstance $Instance -RootDirectory $IndexLocation | Out-Null; 
    if (!$?){throw "Make sure that Index Location `"$IndexLocation`" exists on Server: `"$Server`"";} 
    #Sets our new Search Topology as Active 
    Set-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -Identity $Clone; 
    #Removes the old Search Topology 
    Remove-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -Identity $Current -Confirm:$false; 
    #Now we need to remove the extra Index Component 
    #Gets the Search Topology 
    $Current = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -SearchApplication $SSA -Active; 
    #Creates a copy of the current Search Topology 
    $Clone=New-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -Clone -SearchApplication $SSA -SearchTopology $Current; 
    #Removes the old Index Component from the Search Topology 
    Get-SPEnterpriseSearchComponent -SearchTopology $Clone | ? {($_.GetType().Name -eq "IndexComponent") -and ($_.ServerName -eq $($Instance.Server.Address)) -and ($_.RootDirectory -ne $IndexLocation)} | Remove-SPEnterpriseSearchComponent -SearchTopology $Clone -Confirm:$false; 
    #Sets our new Search Topology as Active 
    Set-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -Identity $Clone; 
    #Removes the old Search Topology 
    Remove-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -Identity $Current -Confirm:$False; 
    Write-Host "The Index has been moved to $IndexLocation on $Server" 
    Write-Host "This will not remove the data from the old index location. You will have to do that manually :)" 
}
```

In the Same pwoershell window, you have to run the below command with your values.

```
Move-SPEnterpriseSearchIndex -SearchServiceName "Search Service Application" -Server "SP2013-WFE" -IndexLocation "C:\Index"
```

[Move SharePoint 2013 Search Index Location](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Move-SharePoint-2013-242869e2)

Also check this one http://consulting.risualblogs.com/blog/2013/09/03/sharepoint-2013move-the-search-index-location/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your approach is supported. The only supported way I know of changing index location is to update search topology (create new based on current active topology, change index location, and switch from active to new topology). I found recently this scripted approach haven't tested it myself but it may do the trick for you [Move-SPEnterpriseSearchIndex.ps1](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Move-SharePoint-2013-242869e2)